# I want to make an installer for my vb.net 2010 desktop application with MySQL and crystal report included

Tags: mysql, vb.net, installation

I have finished a desktop application using vb.net 2010 with MySql as the back end and Crystal Report as a report generator.

I want to create a single simple installer for the three different application so that it is easier for the user to install it without supervision. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a place to ask questions of the form "I want to do X, tell me how".  It's for you to research and find out how to do what you want and then make an attempt to do it.  If that attempt fails, then you can post an appropriate question of the form "I want to do X, this is how I tried to do it, this is what happened when I tried, help me fix it".

Comment: https://www.samlogic.net/visual-installer/tips/tips-pages/create-installation-for-vb-net-application/create-installation-for-vb-net-application.htm Look  at this and give it a go, google is your best friend and if all else fails then come to SO to ask a qs.

Comment: Believe me sir, I tried looking for answers on google but no luck. I tried the clickOnce on the publish module but it doesnt embed the mysql installer and crystal report installer. Thats why i came here for help.

Comment: Check this thread http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?680679-Install-MySQL-before-installing-application